# Header solo visible al top de la pagina

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de hacer que el header de la página solamente sea visible cuando se está al top de la página, es decir, que cuando se haga un scrollDown se cierre, y solamente cuando esté al top se abra.

Hasta ahora tengo justamente que si hacer un scrollUp, sea donde sea, se verá, y eso no es nada cómodo.

```
window.addEventListener('load',()=>{
    let prevScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
    window.onscroll = function(){
        let currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
        if (prevScrollPos > currentScrollPos){
            document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0].style.top = "0";
            document.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0].style.top = "200px";
        } else {
            document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0].style.top = "-200px";
            document.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0].style.top = "0px";
        }
        prevScrollPos = currentScrollPos;
    }
})
```

¿Cómo podría implementarlo?

Comment: Solo verifica que no hay scroll: `if(currentScrollPos == 0) { /* Mostrar */ } else { /* Ocultar */ }`

Comment: Perfecto, me funcionó a las mil maravillas!